# Is it really more efficient to have a local variable for transform here or is Rider being over-zealous?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm just going through a quick C# / Unity crash course (coming from Java) and I recieved a warning about "Repeated property access of a built-in component is inefficient" while working in Jetbrains Rider for the following code snippet.

```
if (Mathf.Abs(horizontalMovement) > Mathf.Epsilon) {
        horizontalMovement += horizontalMovement * Time.deltaTime;
        var position = transform.position;
        horizontalMovement += position.x;

        position = new Vector2(horizontalMovement, position.y);
        //warning is for this line
        transform.position = position;
    }
```

It was already complaining about using transform.position.x and transform.position.y which seemed fair enough so I created the position var but would declaring `var cachedTransform = transform; ...; cachedTransform.position = position` really be more performant here or is the overhead of creating the local variable just going to negate it?

I'm not asking if this is a valid warning in general, it seems to be. I'm asking if it's valid when you're literally just reassigning in the same statement as I am in the last line of my code above

For reference here's what I would end up with if I followed the warning -

```
 if (Mathf.Abs(horizontalMovement) > Mathf.Epsilon) {
            horizontalMovement += horizontalMovement * Time.deltaTime;
            var cachedTransform = transform;
            var position = cachedTransform.position;
            horizontalMovement += position.x;

            position = new Vector2(horizontalMovement, position.y);
            cachedTransform.position = position;
        }
```

Comment: Whenever there's  question of "slow" code, profile it. I was told something was slow on Pro Feel Golf. I profiled it and found out that on 500,000,000 executions of the "slow" thing, we lost 0.5 seconds. Ordinarily this thing wouldn't be called more than 10-100 times. So yes, it was slower, but it was irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sinse you are new to C#, make sure you read up on [properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) if you haven't already done so. Because over-simplified, they are basically special methods that look like a variable to the end user.

Due to them actually being methods, the C# compiler can't know for sure what you are doing to retrieve the value. So that warning might be over-zealous yes, but that depends on the actual property in question. So if you create a property that does a lot of stuff and is very slow as a result, then you get a huge benefit by caching it. If your property is basically just returning a backed field without any checks, then there is little to no benefit caching the property.

On whether the transform property in your question is fast/slow and therefore needs to be cached, see [this forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cache-transform-really-needed.356875/) (I advise you to read the whole thing, or just test it yourself to be sure).

Comment: Note that this is a Unity specific warning in Rider and the reason for it is documented: https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/wiki/Avoid-multiple-unnecessary-property-accesses